# Grey out button until all text boxes have text in ASP

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I am wondering how to gray out a button until all text boxes have text in ASP.NET and or C#. In the image below I want to gray out the commit button. Cheers, Chris!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try similar like this

Check for every input element that it has the value or not and make a global variable which would be true when all the inputs value.

Now enable a button when this variable is true.

```
 $('input').keyup(function() {

        var isEntryPresent = false;
        $('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                isEntryPresent = true;
            }
        });

        if (isEntryPresent) {
            $('#commitInventory').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#commitInventory').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hH49f/)

You may need to use the more specific input selector if there are any other input elements are present on the page. So you should use the specific selector as per your condition.

Comment: You should probably make mention of the fact that your solution depends on jQuery, which the OP does not mention using.

Comment: How does it loop through all the text boxes? They are in a gridview Staticly generated.

Comment: Thank you! Updating these old posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the "change" event rather than on every single keyup/keydown.  Also, you can use a filter to simplify the code for checking for any empty inputs.

[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/km3z5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("change", function(){        
    $("#inp-submit").prop("disabled", anyEmptyInputs());         
  });
});

function anyEmptyInputs(){
     var empty = $("input").filter(function() { return this.value === ""; });
    return empty.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably make mention of the fact that your solution depends on jQuery, which the OP does not mention using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have JavaScript tagged here as well as ASP.NET I'm assuming you are doing this on the Client Side also, or can do it on the Client Side, Below you can run the code Live from JSFiddle

**Click Here For A [Live JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeCowboyOrg/4pFk3/).**

If you run the code on JsFiddle, it basically attaches all the TextBoxes to the "KeyUp" Event and then checks how many TextBoxes are Not Empty comparing it to the count of the Number of Total TextBoxes, if the count of Not Empty matches the count of number of Total TextBoxes then the Commit button is enabled, otherwise its disabled.

The HTML used there are 5 TextBoxes and 1 Button named Commit.  If you are running the code below in your own web page.  **Remember to include JQuery 2.0**

```
<span>TextBox #1</span><input type="text" /><br /><br />
<span>TextBox #2</span><input type="text" /><br /><br />
<span>TextBox #3</span><input type="text" /><br /><br />
<span>TextBox #4</span><input type="text" /><br /><br />
<span>TextBox #5</span><input type="text" /><br /><br />
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Commit" />
```

The JQuery/JavaScript that enables and disables the Commit button based on text in the TextBoxes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    //This routine attaches the "KEYUP" event to every TextBox
    //When the user types each TextBox will be checked every time
    //and count which ones are Not Empty, if the count of the Not Empty
    //TextBoxes equals that of the count of all TextBoxes then the
    //Commit button is Enabled. 
    $('input:text').keyup(function () {
        var isValid = true;
        $('input:text').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                isValid = false;
                return false;
            } 
            if (isValid) {
                $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
```